# How does chaff compare to hay?

Tags: health, feeding, horses

How does chaff compare to hay in terms of nutrition and fibre?
For example, does lucerne chaff contain the same protein levels as lucerne hay?

Comment: you probably know all this but here is a link where you can see the nutitional values http://www.freestock.com.au/chaff/lucerne/

Comment: @trondhansen I'm hoping someone else will write an answer, hence the bounty. I cannot award a bounty to myself :)

Comment: interesting question. We learnt it's the same but for the structure, which I actually am not quite so sure about regarding the proteins. I don't think that chaff loses any fibre, that could only happen if the oligosaccharid (fibre is one) gets broken down to shorter saccharid chains, means is transformed to sugar (which is just what happens when you chew bread). Well, the end of the cut might be affected, but I think that doesn't really count in. About the proteins I am pretty unsure since I believe they are far more vulnerable to manipulations & time. Love to hear the answer from an expert :)

Comment: I think a very interesting (pragmatic) aspect here is, that there are far less producers of chaff which means you can somehow predict what types of grasses and relations they use since that will change a whole lot about what is inside the chaff/hay. I pretty much guess that chaff which is made from a good meadow is always better than hay from a bad meadow and vice versa. What you ask surely is rather the difference when they are made from the same meadow (which is rather unrealistic in most cases, but in theory nice to know). Most chaffs contain some additional substances apart from the grass.

Comment: @MelissaLoos interesting comparing the same hay to chaff, but it could also form part of an answer. You really could write those comments into an answer. There's another issue - the chaff is easier on horses with chewing issues. Particularly if it's wet down. It also serves as a good fibre mixer with hard feed - like "sweet" feeds.

Comment: Yes but it's easier to chew simply because of the length of each haulm. Horses with tooth gaps tend to wind the hay inside their mouths which makes it impossible for the horse to swallow bit by bit. But the structure itself shouldn't contain more or less fibre than uncut unchopped hay. I don't feel like I know enough about the topic to make a good answer of it though, since there is much guesswork/deduction and I would want to do some good research on proteins before (don't have time for that atm) and rather see the answer from a real expert who may include some of my thoughts naturally :)